# How to save JSON data using SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, ios10, swifty-json

I am trying to save data localy using the JSON library. Here is my code at the moment:

```
var jsonFile = "json.json"

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let jsonFile = "file.json"
        let jsonArray:JSON = [
            "array": [12.34, 56.78],
            "users": [
                [
                    "id": 987654,
                    "info": [
                        "name": "jack",
                        "email": "jack@gmail.com"
                    ],
                    "feeds": [98833, 23443, 213239, 23232]
                ],
                [
                    "id": 654321,
                    "info": [
                        "name": "jeffgukang",
                        "email": "jeffgukang@gmail.com"
                    ],
                    "feeds": [12345, 56789, 12423, 12412]
                ]
            ]
        ]



        if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
        {
            let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(jsonFile)

            if(!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path.path))
            {
                FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: path.path, contents: Data(), attributes: nil)
                print("Created file")

                do {
                    try write(json: jsonArray, to: path)
                } catch let error{
                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }

                try! write(json: jsonArray, to: path)
            } else {
                print("File existed")
                do {
                    let myJSON = try readJSON(myURL: path)
                    if let _ = myJSON
                    {
                        print("Got data")
                    } else {
                        print("No Data")
                    }
                } catch let errorOne {
                    print("Error2: \(errorOne.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "json", withExtension: "json")


func readJSON(myURL:URL) throws -> JSON? {

    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    {
        let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(jsonFile)

        if(!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path.path))
        {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: path, options: .alwaysMapped)
            return JSON(data: data)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func write(json: JSON, to url: URL) throws {
    let data = try json.rawData()
    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    {
        let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(jsonFile)

        if(!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path.path))
        {
            try data.write(to: path)
        }
    }
}
```

When you run the program for the first time, it creates the file and 'writes the jsonArray'. When you run it again, it 'loads' the JSON data.

The problem is, the value returned of `readJSON(myURL: path)` is equal to `nil`.

How would I read and write JSON data using SwiftyJSON on ios 10.2?

**Update**

I have executed my application in the `iPhone 6s` simulator and checked the saved file `json.json`. Here is the saved file:

```
{"array":[12.34,56.78],"users":[{"id":987654,"info":{"name":"jack","email":"jack@gmail.com"},"feeds":[98833,23443,213239,23232]},{"id":654321,"info":{"name":"jeffgukang","email":"jeffgukang@gmail.com"},"feeds":[12345,56789,12423,12412]}]}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `try - catch` at all to handle errors?? Aside from that it's pretty ineffective to create the JSON always even if the file in the documents directory exists.

Comment: @vadian This is just code to play around with the library. This code is not going to be used in a project. I just want to know how to save and load JSON data. Also, my program is not crashing. It just returns nil.

Comment: `try - catch` does **not** catch exceptions / crashes. It reports errors. It's highly recommended to use it in all cases an error could occur. Debug your code. Set breakpoints. Use the debugger.

Comment: @vadian I have updated the code with a try catch, however, it does note show anything else.

Comment: What is `readJSON`? It's not a part of SwiftyJSON. You might read the `Data` and initialize a `JSON` object from the data. Have you checked in the file system if the file is written properly? Personally I would not use SwiftyJSON to write JSON to disk because it uses the `prettyPrinted` option which is adding unnecessary spaces and newline characters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132092/discussion-between-iprogram-and-vadian).

Comment: @vadian I have updated the code with the docatch functionality and have shown the output of the file (it does not prettyPrint).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just relised what the problem was.

In the readJSON() function:

```
func readJSON(myURL:URL) throws -> JSON? {

    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    {
        let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(jsonFile)

        if(!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path.path))
        {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: path, options: .alwaysMapped)
            return JSON(data: data)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

the line `if(!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path.path))` should have been `if(FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path.path))`.

Before, I was only loading the data if the file did not exist.